# Rounding function in c++

Tags: c++

```
Output : 21

round(21.4801769) //inbuilt std function
```

it returns the 21 integer value but I need 22 value.

```
round(21.444498)
Output: 21
round function only checks for 1st decimal value.
```

Comment: ceil(21.321) for this input it gives 22. it is not the right method in python how the round function will work that type in need.

Comment: What do you think [std::round](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) does? It computes the nearest **integer** value. Every example in your question is correct.

Comment: round function it checks for the 21.4 value, not 21.49 value. I should round the value based on the number of floating value exist in the given input.

Comment: It rounds to the nearest **INTEGER** value. [Here it is](https://godbolt.org/z/Gfe2dT) running on Compiler Explorer.  It produces `21` just as expected.

Comment: `round(21.4999999)` returns 21 and `round(21.5)` returns 22. That is exactly what I learned in school.

Comment: This is how rounding has worked since forever. It is not specific to C++ or programming.

Answer (score 4):

Use  [`std::ceil()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/ceil) and [`std::floor()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/floor) functions instead of [`std::round()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round).

- `std::round`: returns the integral value that is nearest to
  the argument, with halfway cases, rounded away from zero.
- `std::ceil`: returns the smallest integer that is greater than or
  equal to x (i.e: rounds up the nearest integer).
- `std::floor`: returns the largest integer that is smaller than or
  equal to x (i.e: rounds downs the nearest integer).

```cpp
  std::ceil(21.444498)  = 22
  std::floor(21.444498) = 21
  std::round(21.444498) = 21
  std::round(21.510000) = 22
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ceil()`. (Assuming you always want to round the value up)

For example:

```
float float_value = 21.4801769;
int answer = ceil(float_value);        // Gives 22
```

And `#include <cmath>` for it.